# Finding Places without providing nearby location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps, I can type in 'Eiffel Tower' and it will present the correct location/Place. But using the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) with Maps API, it seems that you must always provide a nearby location when searching. You can't search for 'Eiffel Tower', it has to be 'Eiffel Tower' and you have to provide coordinates for 'Paris, France' as well. Is there any way to achieve an API experience closer to the regular Google Maps experience?

UPDATE:

If I search with the regular Maps API Geocoder, 'Eiffel Tower' does in fact return the correct address. But if I search Geocoder with 'Madison Square Garden', I receive completely unrelated locations. This is despite the fact that the Google Maps website does immediately identify 'Madison Square Garden' correctly.

Summary: It seems that the Places Library cannot search Places without a nearby Location provided. Additionally, Geocoder can sometimes search for famous places but not other times. Results do not seem to correspond to the Google Maps website results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search in Google Maps, you ARE providing a "nearby" location. It uses the center/bounds of the current map view. Searching for a place without context wouldn't be very helpful.